# finding difference among record values in same column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking to find difference between two values in same column at specific window in table.

Data:

```
date        sid category    st  st_status   %discount
20/05/22    123 c1          az  in_stock          12
20/05/22    123 c1          ph  in_stock          10
20/05/22    123 c1          mg  out_of_stock      20
20/05/22    345 c2          mg  out_of_stock    
20/05/22    345 c2          az  in_stock           2
20/05/22    789 c3          mg  in_stock           0
20/05/22    789 c3          ph  out_of_stock
```

Expected results:

```
date        sid category    st  st_status   %discount   parity
20/05/22    123 c1          az  in_stock       12       lead
20/05/22    123 c1          ph  in_stock       10       lead
20/05/22    123 c1          mg  in_stock       20   
20/05/22    345 c2          mg  out_of_stock        
20/05/22    345 c2          az  in_stock        2        lag
20/05/22    789 c3          mg  in_stock        0   
20/05/22    789 c3          ph  out_of_stock             lead
```

Note : The parity is w.r.t `mg` & if `mg` is `in_stock` but others are `out_of_stock` then `parity` will be lead for `mg` else vice versa.
Moreover, If the difference between `mg` & `other st values` for specific sid is `+ve` then parity is `lead` else `lag`

It would be great if `st` column is in pivot form for every date & sid.

What I have tried:

```
select date, sid, category, st, st_status, %discount, lag(%discount) over (partition by date, sid, st order by date) as lag_discount
from table1
```

This will not work as my date is fixed as a window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below, solution is using conditional logic via `case` statements -

```
with data_cte as
(
select 
date1,sid,category,st,st_status,discount,condition1,
case when st = 'mg' then null
when tab.condition1 > 0 OR tab.condition2 = 1 then 'lead'
when  tab.condition1 < 0 OR tab.condition2 = 0 then 'lag'
end
lead_lag
from 
(
select *,
case when 
(select count(*) from test t1
 where t1.date1 = t.date1
     and t1.sid = t.sid
     and t1.category = t.category
     and t1.st = 'mg'
     and t1.discount is null) > 0  
  then -1
else
sum(
case when st = 'mg' 
  then discount * (-1) 
  else discount end) 
 over (partition by date1, sid,category 
order by null) 
end condition1,
case when st = 'mg' then null
when st<>'mg' and st_status = 'out_of_stock'
and (select count(*) from test t1
 where t1.date1 = t.date1
     and t1.sid = t.sid
     and t1.category = t.category
     and t1.st <> 'mg'
     and t1.st_status = 'in_stock') = 0
and (select count(*) from test t1
 where t1.date1 = t.date1
     and t1.sid = t.sid
     and t1.category = t.category
     and t1.st = 'mg'
     and t1.st_status = 'in_stock') > 0
 then 1 else 0 end condition2
from test t
) tab
)
select date1, sid,
max(case when st = 'mg' then lead_lag end) 
'mg',
max(case when st='az' then lead_lag end) 
'az',
max(case when st = 'ph' then lead_lag end) 
'ph'
from data_cte
group by date1,sid;
```

Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w2HjKXJ9CrGj7pubggYxuz/2) without pivot.

Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w2HjKXJ9CrGj7pubggYxuz/1) including  pivot.